# laravel form search for the data which is not available in the database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

hello i am trying to implement search in my application.
here is what i have done so far
in my index method

```
    public function index()
    {

        $search=request()->query('search');

        if($search)
        {
            $city = City::where('name', request()->query('search'))->first();
            $tution = Tution::where('city_id', $city->id)->paginate(3);

           return view('ShowTutions.AllTutions')->with('tution',$tution)
        ->with('user',User::all())->with('city',City::all());   

        }


            return view('ShowTutions.AllTutions')->with('tution',Tution::Paginate(3))
            ->with('user',User::all())->with('city',City::all());


    }
```

it works completely find but the problem is if user enters a value which is not in the database it shows the error
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
what i really want if there is no tution which is realted to that city it should show no result found .

Comment: Check if city and tution are set before returning the view.

Comment: how can i peroform check i am learner please don't mind..

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because a user searched for something that isnt there. 
You could fix it like this:

```
  if($search)
        {
            $city = City::where('name', request()->query('search'))->first();
            $tution = Tution::where('city_id', $city->id)->paginate(3);

 if(!isEmpty($city) && !isEmpty($tution)){

           return view('ShowTutions.AllTutions')->with('tution',$tution)
        ->with('user',User::all())->with('city',City::all());   
}
        }
```

But for searching large amounts of data i would suggest looking into ajax. This will handle the request so that the user doesnt get redirected everytime he tries to look for something